# workflow branch on update/add/delete

Tags: designer-workflow

Is there a way to branch in a list workflow created using SharePoint Designer based on how the workflow was triggered?

For example, if I add a record I want to add to a variable based on the new record. But if a record is deleted, I want to subtract.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the workflow context variable and check the association start on change and start on create fields. Those are the only fields I know you can use to determine what kind of operation is occurring.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but I thought those only tell you if the workflow is *configured* to start on those events. Are you saying they tell you which event *started this workflow context*?

Comment: Let me verify that I just checked real quick but didn't actually make a workflow...